# How can I test `perform_now` job in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rails-activejob

Recently on my current project, I noticed that on our integration test, there are many `assert_enqueued_jobs 1` code are commented out, then I ask other developer about it, He told me that we've changed many **ActiveJob** `perform_later` call to `perform_now` for speed reason, and that `assert_enqueued_jobs` can't catch those performed now jobs.

I've tried using `assert_performed_jobs` also but didn't worked out.

Can anyone give me insight or suggestion to test it? or it just can't be testable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untestable? Never!

The `assert_enqueded_jobs` is not actually testing code, rather checking that something was actually enqueued to happen later. If something happens right away, why test that it was enqueued?

I would try to keep the queue and force jobs to be performed/cleared using other of the `ActiveJob::TestHelpers`. But to that's just me, it makes little difference.

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveJob/TestHelper/assert_enqueued_jobs

Say your job was to send some email, just call the `ActiveJob#perform_now` and check `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count`. At this point, the actual test will be very tailored to the job.

Could be creating a `Notification` and you might want to assert that `Notification.count` has changed, whatever.

The main thing is that instead of checking that the job was enqueued and end of story, we're looking for the desired outcome from that job running.